# Laravel 5 inserting row with a foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have two tables Users and Posts.
here is my User table migration file:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password', 60);
        $table->string('password_temp',60);
        $table->integer('active');
        $table->string('code',60);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('users');
}
```

and here is my posts table migration file

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function(Blueprint $table){

        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('body');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('slug');
        $table->timestamps();


    });

    Schema::table('posts',function(Blueprint $table){

        $table->foreign('user_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade')
            ->onUpdate('cascade');

    });
}
```

AdminPostsController extends Controller{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

```
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),Post::$rules);


    if($validator->passes()){



        $post = new Post();

        $post->title = $request->get('title');
        $post->body = $request->get('body');
        $post->user_id = $request->get('id');
        $post->slug = Slug::generateSlug($request->get('title'));

        $post->save();

        return Redirect::route('admin.posts.index');
    }
    else{
            return Redirect::route('admin.posts.create')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }

}
```

}

Every time i insert a new post,i always see the following error

"`QueryException in Connection.php line 614:
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails ('blog'.'posts', CONSTRAINT 'posts_user_id_foreign' FOREIGN KEY ('user_id') REFERENCES 'users' ('id') ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)`"

i would like to know what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Sounds like you didn't insert the post with a valid `user_id`. Can you show us how you create the new post?

Comment: I just added the store function @lukasgeiter

Comment: Instead of setting `user_id` and `slug` on the `$post` you do so on `$request`

Comment: Thank you, i just edited the function, but im still getting the same result
@lukasgeiter

Comment: Is `$request->get('id')` even set? Do `dd($request->get('id'))` to check

Comment: you write, it return a null value @lukasgeiter

Comment: here is my select from field for user:
<div class="form-group">
                    {!!Form::label('user_id', 'User Name: ')!!}
                    {!!Form::select('user_id',app\User::lists('name','id'),array('class'=>'form-control'))!!}
                </div>
@lukasgeiter

Comment: Then retrieve it with `$request->get('user_id')`

Comment: I am so stupid. Thanks a lot @lukasgeiter.
Ps: When is your portfolio luskasgeiter.com gonna be available

Comment: You're welcome! Puh I don't know. At the moment I'm busy working on other things...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This code creates a constrain so that your post MUST be referenced by a valid user id. The `user_id` field must contain a existing key on the users table id field.

```
    $table->foreign('user_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('users')
```

Try associating the user before saving the new post.

```
$post        = new Post();
$post->title = $request->get('title');
$post->body  = $request->get('body');

$post->user()->associate($user);
$post->save();
```

Assuming that you have a valid user model loaded on the `$user` var and that you have set the relationship between Users and Posts on the Models.

Comment: I have made the chages. I think the problem is the $request->get('id')